# Is it possible to have client-side rendering with angularjs and server-side rendering with thymeleaf using Jhipster?

Tags: angularjs, thymeleaf, jhipster

When I choose monolithic application via 'yo jhipster', it only give option to go with AngularJS.

Is there an option to generate jhipster scaffolding application which supports both client-side rendering with angularjs and server-side rendering with thymeleaf?

Comment: all options are documented at jhipster.github.io. Thymaleaf is imported and used for mail templates, but there is no full server side client

Comment: David is right, generator will not help but it's not that difficult to do it manually